Exception caught by image resource service(flutter)
when i try to run the code it show's me that:
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device Pixel 6...
Reloaded 0 libraries in 270ms (compile: 10 ms, reload: 0 ms, reassemble: 47 ms).
======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: "images/dice1.png".

Exception: Asset not found
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.loadBuffer (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:368:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:757:16)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MultiFrameImageStreamCompleter._handleCodecReady (package:flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart:1013:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "images/dice1.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#e521c(), name: "images/dice1.png", scale: 1.0)

==================================================================================================== run report
this is my pubspec.yaml file:
pubspec.yaml code

check did u insert the image path on pubspec.yaml

Please avoid showing your code/config with an image link. Please edit your question to get a higher chance of being answered.
